# Torsion divisor on non-hyperelliptic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $P$ and $Q$ are two points on a curve $C$. We say $P-Q$ is a torsion divisor if $dP-dQ$ is a principle divisor for some positive integer $d$.

For hyperelliptic curves, Grant proved a Nagell-Lutz like theorem in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X12001163) for torsion divisors. I wonder if there is an easy-to-use criteria for torsion divisors on non-hyperelliptic curves.